# Blender can denoise its own animations. Can it denoise a live shot?

Tags: denoise

I have a drone with a small camera on it which can get noisy even with a rock-bottom ISO of 100. I have been experimenting with color correcting my drone videos in Blender and being able to denoise them as well  in the same program would be quite convenient. Is this possible?

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you, but my machine runs on Linux. I've got other options though so no worries!

Comment: I was wrong, you can denoise your images with the denoiser ! See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/178169/86891

Comment: @Gorgious I'll have to look into that, thank you!

Comment: I haven't tried this, so I don't want to submit it as an answer, but just a suggestion.  What if you placed your footage as an image on a plane in a 3D scene (of course giving it an emission texture with brightness strength of 1.0) with the image taking up the whole view of the camera.  Then render it with one of the denoising options on?

Comment: @Blazer003 Interesting. If an opportunity arises to try it out, I'll have to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am, answering my own question. I have not found any way at all to use Blender to remove camera noise. The AI Denoise node now included with Blender does not affect live-action footage.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using another opensource program for that... maybe Natron, its similar to Nuke but has only 2D capabilities so far. But good for compositing basics:

https://natrongithub.github.io/

I think it has a Denoise/sharp node that you could try.

Good Luck. Stay Safe